# browser.url(url) - browser doesn't open in call back function

Tags: url, browser, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to open the browser with a url which is created dynamically (needs to fetch accessToken first and include in the url) -

```
openDocument(browser,username,password) {
    this.getAccessToken(username,password,(accessToken) => {
        var url = browser.launch_url.replace("accessTokenValue",     accessToken);
        browser.url(url);
    })
}
```

For some reason the browser does not open when client.url(url) is part of the callback function.
If I move it outside the callback function it works fine and opens the browser (but I don't have the accessToken yet)

Comment: what does openDocument and getAccessToken return ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat new to Nightwatch but I think if you want to perform async operations in a callback or (as the doc says) "read variables set by other commands", you can use browser.perform to manage the event completion.  Here's a working example with a `.url` call in a callback:

```
module.exports = {
    'example' : function(browser) {
        var getAccessToken = function(fn) {
            setTimeout(fn, 1000);
        };
        browser
            .perform(function(client, done) {
                getAccessToken(function() {
                    client.url("http://stackoverflow.com", done);
                });
            })
            .waitForElementVisible("#mainbar");
    }
}
```